# How dialog create dividers between action buttons

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, divider

I have a problem while trying to create a dialog with custom actions button.  To create a divider between actions, currently, I added one view as a divider as image below, but when inspecting layout of system alert dialog, they don't do like that. I tried to find the source code of AlertDialog but haven't found the way they created a divider.

So, I hope someone can show me the way to create gray dividers between actions button like the system does.

Thank you so much,
[image]

Comment: Please give any sample image which you want to create.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: The divider between buttons generally depends on the style used. You can in fact make your own AlertDialog with your own layout (including buttons and its separator).

Comment: i just want to know how system create gray divider between action buttons like images above